# Setting ag grid standalone chart min x axis value doesnt work

Tags: javascript, charts, ag-grid

Im trying to explicitly set the min value for the x axis but for some reason the chart still uses 0 instead of the value im providing.

```
standAloneChartOptions = {
  container: document.getElementById('myChart'),
  autoSize: true,
  data: someData,
  series: [
    {
      xKey: 'foo',
      yKey: 'bar',
      yName: 'Bar',
      stroke: '#03a9f4',
      marker: {
        fill: '#03a9f4',
        stroke: '#0276ab',
      },
      tooltipEnabled: false,
    }
  ],
  axes: [
    {
      type: 'number',
      position: 'top',
      title: {
        enabled: true,
        text: 'Foo'
      },
      min: 50,
      max: 1000,
      tick: {
        count: 20
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'number',
      position: 'left',
    },
  ],
  legend: {
    position: 'bottom',
  },
};
```

the max value is set accordingly so im confused as to what im doing wrong, would much appreciate the help, thanks!